# How can i set the date to the beginning of calendar

Tags: javascript, date, time

I want to set the time to the `1st January 0000` and time at `00:00:00` i tried to calculate a lot but i'm unable to set the date to the beginning point.

I am setting the date with negative sign like this -

`new Date(-4000)` but setting the year to 0 gives me only the `1900` so how can get to the perfect date of `1st Jan 0000` and time at `00:00:00`.

Comment: `new Date('0000-01-01')`. The Gregorian calendar was introduced in 1582, any date before then is an extrapolation. The concept of "the beginning of the calendar" is likely not 1 Jan 0000.

Comment: Thanks Rob, i was doing it wrong way i was converting the year to milliseconds, considering that the one years one day  is about `86400000` milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function d() {
let d = new Date('1  January 0000, 00:00:00');
alert(d);
}
```

```html
<input type=button onClick="d()" value="Click">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date(0) // Thu Jan 01 1970 05:30:00
```

This can be seen as the reference against which all the dates or times are calculated in Javascript. Now you need to find the time difference in milliseconds from the reference to the time you have mentioned.

This could be calculated, and one would end up with a huge number doing this.
The best way I can recommend is to use the API to set Date and Time at what one desires.
This ensures a more readable and efficient code that calculating this offset or storing it in your code.

The code below should work without the need for a huge magic number. The best part even the time is set to what was mentioned in the question.

```
let now = new Date();
now.setHour(0);
now.setMinute(0);
now.setSeconds(0);
now.setMilliseconds(0);
now.setFullYear(0,0,1);

let ad0 = new Date(now);
console.log(ad0); // Jan 01 0000 00:00:00
```